Html2canvas is not giving me darker image in angular for a graph image which is rendered on screen
I have a animated chart graph which is represented in my UI Screen whenever i am using Html2Canvas it is capturing the image but in very light way. I have to take that image and put it in a PDF.
const element = document.getElementById(divId);
html2canvas(element, { scale: 2, logging: false, useCORS: true, allowTaint: true}).then(canvas => {

const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);

// now i have to use that img in PDF //

}

I tried adding timeout and converting the image to jpg or png. still not working
